# Simple Algebra ,Radicals ,Prime Numbers

Tags: calculus

a,b are prime numbers
c∈ℕ

2√a + 7√b = c√3

a²+b²+c²=?

I don't really know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

$$2\sqrt{\frac a3}+7\sqrt{\frac b3}\in\mathbb N$$ is only possible if the radicals have rational values (no linear combination of irrationals gives an integer).

Then, only one prime gives the square of a rational when divided by $3$:  obviously $3$. From this, $c=9$.

Answer (score 1):

$a=b=3$, $c=9$. $a^2+b^2+c^2=99$.